# Is the deleteArchivedFiles.php script run automatically?

Tags: mediawiki

I occasionally upload new versions of files (pdf or image files) on my wiki.  I delete the old ones but I think Mediawiki doesn't really delete them [as per this](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Image_administration#Deletion_of_images).  So, I ran the `deleteArchivedFiles.php` maintenance script and it reported only **1 File** was deleted.  Either the script has a problem or it automatically runs sometimes, because I was expecting hundreds.

Do maintenance scripts run on some schedule?  Sorry if this is dumb question, I haven't found anything in my search.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you set up a cron job, maintenance scripts will not run automatically.

More importantly, `deleteArchivedFiles.php` deletes *deleted* files, which are stored in `images/deleted` directory and `filearchive` table; not the ones replaced with new versions, that are stored in `images/archive` directory and `oldimage` table.

I don't think there is a maintenance script that removes old versions of files. It can be done manually, though.